Is there a connection between the generalized Cauchy formula for repeated integration and the Riemann zeta function?
I know that the formula for the Riemann zeta function is:
$$\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x - 1} \, dx$$
And that Cauchy's formula for repeated integration is:
$$(J^nf)(x) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_0^x (x - t)^{n-1} f(t) \, dt$$
I was reading the Wikipedia article on fractional calculus and realized that the generalized formula, using the gamma function, takes a similar form to the above representation of the Riemann zeta function.
$$(J^nf)(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)} \int_0^x (x - t)^{n-1} f(t) \, dt$$
Is there some significance to this, perhaps in the context of representing the Riemann zeta function with repeated integrals, or am I mistaken?

There is multiple integral for the riemann zeta function, but it's not a cauchy like integral. You could try to perhaps convert this into a repeated integral
